# NetStream.Play.Failed with VideoTexture on iOS in Adobe Air App

Tags: ios, video, air, starling-framework, away3d

I'm trying to get a video to play in an `Away3d` texture on iOS. It's fine on Android and Windows.  The video will play in Starling on iOS so I know it's not the video.

Here is how I add the video:

```
        sphereGeometry = new SphereGeometry(5000, 64, 48);
        panoTextureMaterial = new TextureMaterial(panoTexture2DBase, false, false, false);

        panoVideoMesh = new Mesh(sphereGeometry, panoTextureMaterial);
        panoVideoMesh.scaleX *= -1;

        panoVideoMesh.rotate(Vector3D.Y_AXIS,-90);

        scene.addChild(panoVideoMesh);
        panoTexture2DBase.player.play();
        view.render();
```

On iOS I get this from the netstats when I try and load it as a video texture.

```
NetStream.Play.Start
NetStream.Play.Failed
NetStream.Play.Stop
```

I'm using the `Away3d` `NativeVideoTexture` class

```
        texture = context.createVideoTexture();
            texture.attachNetStream(_player.ns);
```

I think it might be do with MP4 encoding, and I've had  a good look around and can't find anything that works, currently I'm trying this in FFMEG

```
-vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -level 3.1 -crf 23 -s 1024:768 -movflags +faststart
```

But what I set doesn't seem to make a lot of difference.

Any idea why my video is failing to load as a VideoTexture on iOS?